# Css animation: typing out the words, not working with html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a typing effect to my h1 text. I was just trying to simply make the text write out using css animation. The text isn't writing out though. Could somebody please help me thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="techBox">
   <div class="techTitle"><h1>Website Design</h1></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.techBox {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 150, 5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgb(0, 150, 5);
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 750px;
    left: 150px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.techTitle h1{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 450px;
    letter-spacing: .10em;
    border-right: .15em solid rgb(0, 150, 5);
    color: rgb(0, 150, 5);
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
    animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end);
    animation: caret .75s step-end infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

 @keyframes typing {
    from {width: 0}
    to {width: 100%;}
}

@keyframes caret {
    from, to{border-color: transparent}
    50% {border-color: rgb(0, 150, 5)}
}
```

Comment: You're missing your `@keyframes typing {}` code.

Comment: Sorry I did add that. I edited the code